# Using C# to get multiple results into GridView cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Very new to writing code, please be gentle...

I have a database that keeps track of images that I post online, who was in the image, date taken, etc.  I then have an ASPX page that based on the ID I pass in brings me back a gridview of the image, location online etc.  This helps me keep track of how many places I may have used a single image.

Everything works great, but I get one row per image URL in my grid view.  I want to have the image appear once on my page, then one of the cells list out the URLs.

Here is my C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db2257conn"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select mFirstName, mDOB, cURL, fID, fURL, cDate from vwAllModelContent where " + Context.Request.QueryString["mID"] + " IN(mID1, mID2, mID3) and cactive = 1 order by cDate, fType, fName, cURL";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
    protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Here is the ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="modelcontent2.aspx.cs" Inherits="modeldatabase.modelcontent2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            <Columns>
                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="fURL" DataTextField="furl" DataTextFormatString="<img src='{0}' width='200' border='0' />" Target="_blank" HeaderText="Image Link" Text="Image Link" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="cDate" HeaderText ="Shoot Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField ="mFirstName" HeaderText="Model First Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mDOB" HeaderText="DOB" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fID" HeaderText="File ID" />
                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="cURL" DataTextField="cURL" HeaderText ="URL" Target="_blank" Text="URL" />
               </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my rep is too new to post an image of the results, but suffice it to say I see multiple rows for the same image, one for each URL.

I'd like to see the image and other data as a single row, then in the URL column have all of the URLs that the image appears at.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some code in the `OnDataBound` Event that were you could do the specific formatting of the link that you need.. also I don't see why you would need to make multiple Database calls unless I am not understanding something here...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very performant but try a subselect

```
         String strQuery = "select mFirstName, mDOB, (SELECT cURL + ',' FROM vwAllModelContent where " + Context.Request.QueryString["mID"] + " IN (mID1, mID2, mID3)) , fID, fURL, cDate from vwAllModelContent where " + Context.Request.QueryString["mID"] + " IN(mID1, mID2, mID3) and cactive = 1 order by cDate, fType, fName, cURL LIMIT 1";
```

I'm not sure if it works, didn't use sql for a long time

Question: Why do you have three columns for IDs? (mID1, mID2, mID3)

Comment: mID denotes the person/model in the image.  So if there are multiple models in an image I can segregate that data

Answer (score 0):

What you are defining is called a "1 to many" relationship.

Gridview's are designed to show multiple rows tabular type data.  If you want to display 1 image and multiple rows of associated data there are several ways of doing this.

Typically this would require 2 database calls:

- one that returns the image source link
- one that returns the rows of associated data.

Since the first call is really only providing an `img src` you don't really need a databound control for that, just obtain the string and drop it into an `<asp:Image />` control or an `<asp:ImageButton />` (if you prefer the image to be a link) and set the **`ImageUrl`** property

The second call is returning multiple rows of data, use your existing Gridview, you only need to remove the image reference.

Comment: The two query thing is what I was trying to do initially, what I run into is I want the "1" to be the image, the date of the shoot, the name, the model dob, and the file id, the "many" I want to be the URLs.  So I'm not really sure how to bind that all together.

Comment: What tables contain the data you need?

Comment: I actually am calling a view.  I didn't want the page doing any direct table selects.  But the view joins on 6 tables.

Comment: then create 2 views - one that returns a single row containing the image and it's associated info and another that returns the URL's